# Why does web.config not work successfully?

Tags: iis-7

I have read through and tried implementing various documentation regarding '500 - internal server error'; however nothing seems to work.

https://nkfaulknerandsons.co.uk/

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="HTTPS Rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://(HTTP_HOST)(REQUEST_URI)" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false">
        </urlCompression>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="untitled-1.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <compilation debug="true" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Use FRT to learn more, and also try to handle unhandled exceptions in your web app.

Comment: could you please provide the detailed error message snapshot and when you get this error?